# ECDiffieHellman - mbedTLS vs C#

Tags: c#, c, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman, mbedtls

I need to use elliptic curve Diffie Hellman between a ARM cortex M3 and the PC.
On the ARM, I use [mbed TLS](https://tls.mbed.org/). On the PC side I want to us C# and the [ECDiffieHellman(Cng)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

I can do the ECDH on ARM vs ARM, but I do have trouble when I try to replace one side with the PC.

1. Problem was the key exchange.
   I found out, that the key is exported by mbed TLS as `<LEN><0x04><X><Y>`.

Thus, In C# I am importing the public key using

private static EC

```cs
DiffieHellmanPublicKey ToPublicKey(byte[] publicKey)
{
    var keyLength = 32;

    if (publicKey[0] != (2 + 2 * keyLength) - 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key length", nameof(publicKey));
    if (publicKey[1] != 0x04)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key format", nameof(publicKey));

    var parameters = new ECParameters()
    {
        Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1,
        Q = new ECPoint()
        {
            X = publicKey.Skip(2).Take(keyLength).ToArray(),
            Y = publicKey.Skip(2 + keyLength).Take(keyLength).ToArray()
        }
    };

    using (var tmp = ECDiffieHellman.Create(parameters))
    {
        return tmp.PublicKey;
    }
}
```

2. To generate the key I tried

```cs
var ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1);
ecdh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Tls;
ecdh.Seed = new byte[32];
ecdh.Label = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ECDiffieHellman");

new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(ecdh.Seed);

// ...

var sharedSecret = ecdh.DeriveKeyMaterial(peersPublicKey);
```

My problem is that the generated shared secret is of different length compared to the one generated by mbed TLS and does not match.

Did someone already solve this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

I forgot to mention, that I use bare ECDH on ARM. So I don't think there is any key derivation function executing. Is it sufficient to hash (SHA256) the result to match the C# side (when configuring SHA256 as KDF there)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. In short: just hash the ECDH result.

**C/C++ side:**

1. EC Diffie Hellman

```c
mbedtls_ecdh_init(...);
mbedtls_ecdh_setup(...);
mbedtls_ecdh_make_public(...); //make own public key and send it to peer
mbedtls_ecdh_read_public(...); //reed peers public key
mbedtls_ecdh_calc_secret(...); //note: i pass in my own RND func because of no OS
mbedtls_ecdh_free(...);
```

2. SHA256

```c
mbedtls_sha256_init(...);
mbedtls_sha256_starts_ret(...);
mbedtls_sha256_update_ret(...);
mbedtls_sha256_finish_ret(...);
mbedtls_sha256_free(...);
```

**C# side:**

```cs
private void EllipticCurveDiffieHellman()
{
    var ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1);

    ecdh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
    ecdh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

    //get relevant point from own public key
    var ownPublicKey = ecdh.PublicKey.ExportExplicitParameters().Q;

    var peersPublicKey = SendPublicKey(ownPublicKey); //key exchange
    var sharedSecret = ecdh.DeriveKeyMaterial(peersPublicKey);

    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + HexValue.Parse(sharedSecret.ToArray()));
}

DiffieHellmanPublicKey ToPublicKey(byte[] publicKey)
{
    var keyLength = 32;

    if (publicKey[0] != (2 + 2 * keyLength) - 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key length", nameof(publicKey));
    if (publicKey[1] != 0x04)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid key format", nameof(publicKey));

    var parameters = new ECParameters()
    {
        Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1,
        Q = new ECPoint()
        {
            X = publicKey.Skip(2).Take(keyLength).ToArray(),
            Y = publicKey.Skip(2 + keyLength).Take(keyLength).ToArray()
        }
    };

    using (var tmp = ECDiffieHellman.Create(parameters))
    {
        return tmp.PublicKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please comment, if I did not express myself clearly.

Comment: For optimizations see https://tls.mbed.org/kb/how-to/how-do-i-tune-elliptic-curves-resource-usage

Comment: Use MBEDTLS_ECP_NIST_OPTIM to add optimization for NIST elliptic curves.